# How can I achieve the result I want using sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data in my database. I tried to do a retrieval and it should appear in such a way.

Current table:

```
FName| lName | phoneNo | year
Tom  | Tan   | 9123456 | 1  
Tom  | Tan   | 9012345 | 1 <----extra row
```

What I want:

```
FName | lName| phoneNo| year | phoneNo2
Tom   | Tan  | 9123456| 1    |9012345
```

How can I achieve this using sql statement?

I would like to see if FName and lName are duplicated, then the duplicated data will be combined as such the phoneNo will be added into one column called phoneNo2.

Comment: @Dhwani i went to google and what i saw was pivot. However, i'm not sure how pivot can be applied in my scenario

Comment: Are you sure that there will not be more than 2 rows of the same FName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `MIN()` to get first phoneno and `MAX()` to get the second.

```
select FName, lName, min(phoneNo), max(year), max(phoneNo)
from tablename
group by FName, lName
```

You can also do a self `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.FName, t1.lName, t1.phoneNo, t1.year, t2.phoneNo
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2
    on t1.FName = t2.FName and t1.lName = t2.lName
    and t1.phoneNo < t2.phoneNo
```

**Note:** According to ANSI SQL `YEAR` is a reserved word, so you may need to delimit it as `"year"`.

Comment: It's working. Thanks. I will accept this as the answer in a few minutes time due to the restriction of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which will cope with more than 2 phone numbers is to use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT FName, 
    lName,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(phoneNo), ',', 1) AS phoneNo, 
    `year`, 
    IF(COUNT(phoneNo) >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(phoneNo), ',', 2), ',', -1), NULL) AS phoneNo2, 
    IF(COUNT(phoneNo) >= 3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(phoneNo), ',', 3), ',', -1), NULL) AS phoneNo3, 
    IF(COUNT(phoneNo) >= 4, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(phoneNo), ',', 4), ',', -1), NULL) AS phoneNo4, 
    IF(COUNT(phoneNo) >= 5, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(phoneNo), ',', 5), ',', -1), NULL) AS phoneNo5 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY FName, 
        lName,
        `year`
```